# Optimizar SQL Server (Tengo muchos waiting tasks)

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, entity-framework, ado.net

Tengo un problema con mi base de datos (Microsoft SQL Server), tenemos muchos usuarios usando nuestra API y esta API hace muchas consultas a nuestra base de datos (es normal porque estamos guardando datos de seguimiento), estamos usando un load balancer para nuestra API para que podamos manejar muchas solicitudes pero esto nos dio el problema que es que por la mañana todo funciona bien pero cuando pasa el día todo va muy lento, revisé el monitor de actividad (no soy un DBA pero el equipo no tiene uno) y noté que cuando va lento es cuando aumentan las tareas de espera (waiting tasks), siempre es mayor a 500 (las tareas de espera siempre están alrededor de 500-800), por eso hablé con mi gerente que tampoco es técnico y alquilamos un servidor que solo ejecutará la base de datos (al principio todo estaba en el mismo servidor que la API), estas son las especificaciones:

- 128 ram,16 vcpus

[image: Server specs]

**PERO EL PROBLEMA NO SE RESOLVIÓ, seguimos igual:**

[image: Actvity monitor of database]

Revisé el task manager y me di cuenta que la base de datos ni está usando el 100% de CPU NI RAM.
[image: task manager]

Me gustaría que un experto me recomiende qué hacer porque tengo el hardware y no está mejorando :(, gracias de antemano.

Información extra:

- Nuestra API está usando entity framework, escuché que usar ADO.NET puede mejorar esto, ¿es cierto?
- ¿Comprar una instancia de AZURE (SQL AZURE DATABASE) con el tier business-critical puede resolver nuestro problema? Claro, tendría que migrar todo a la nube pero si esa es la solución lo haría porque ya me cansé.
- SQL Standard edition
- Propiedades de la  SQL INSTANCE:

[image: properties]
[image: Memory]
[image: Processors]
[image: Connections]
[image: Advance]

Comment: Probablemente es un tema de consultas que se demoran demasiado, lo mejor es ver las consultas más pesadas de la aplicación y ver si añadiendo índices puede mejorar. Es lo más habitual.

Comment: Aunque compartes bastantes detalles, es probable que esto sea demasiado amplio para el sitio. Hay muchas cosas que se pueden revisar y la optimización es un trabajo complejo. Puedes buscar el libro "Troubleshooting SQL Server: A Guide for Accidental DBAs" es gratis pero está en inglés.

Comment: @RogerTorné Lo más habitual es que las consultas estén mal hechas y agregando índices probablemente no mejore mucho.

Comment: Aunque la pregunta esta bien, esto requiere un analisis profundo y on site.. ver las tareas, verificar conexiones que no queden abiertas, chequear el pool de la base de datos. Por mas que sea una pregunta valida, las respuestas solo seran mas ideas y mas tips que no se si van a solucionar algo. a mi gusto, necesitarias ayuda on site mas que los tips que te puedan tirar aca. yo no la voy a cerrar, pero tene en cuenta que puede que ni encuentres una solucion aca.

Comment: @RogerTorné Precisamente por eso adiciono la pregunta de que si reprogramando nuestra API  de entity framework a ADO.net hará alguna diferencia, Luis Cazares revisaré ese libro ya que realmente me hice un DBA de forma accidental, he agregado índices pero no hay mucha mejora que digamos, se sigue saturando y pensé que mejorando el hardware nos iba cubrir pero no sé si hay alguna configuración que estoy perdiendo de mi vista porque no está usando el 100% de ram o cpu pero sí está saturado..

Comment: @gbianchi precisamente el pool al aumentar el tráfico de la API se acaban las conexiones, pensé que aumentando el hardware me iba a aumentar el número de conexiones pero aparentemente así no funciona, me gustaría que me aclares ese punto, también por eso pregunto que si migrando a la nube (AZURE DB) puede beneficiarme a manejar esas conexiones porque creo que tener la db en el servidor virtual ya se está quedando corto.

Comment: EF genera las consultas por si mismo... tal vez, en algunos casos, tenga mucho overhead en las consultas que hace... por eso te dijimos que hay mucho que revisar para poder generar una respuesta valida...

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolverlo, reduje las waiting tasks de 500 a 10-25 sin modificar el load balancer de mi API, la solución fue simple y efectiva:

```
USE master
GO

/** 
 * Cut off live connections
 * This will roll back any open transactions after 30 seconds and
 * restricts access to the DB to logins with sysadmin, dbcreator or
 * db_owner roles
 */
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK AFTER 30 SECONDS
GO

-- Enable RCSI for MyDB
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
GO

-- Allow connections to be established once again
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET MULTI_USER
GO

-- Check the status afterwards to make sure it worked
SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = 'DBName'
```

Lo que pasa es que SQL SERVER por default le da prioridad a la consistencia de datos y cuando un usuario escribe sobre las tablas las bloquea y si en tus queries no consideraste esto (con el hint(nolock)) y le diste prioridad a la consistencia de datos es por eso que se encola todo. Es por eso que el CPU ni la RAM se estában usando al 100% porque la mayoría del tiempo tiene tareas pendientes, haciendo el cambio con el código le cambia el modo de "me importa la consistencia" a "me importa velocidad aunque me traigas datos que no pueden estar al 100% actualizados", lo que hace es que crea otra db llamada tempdb y cada que hagas una inserción se hace una copia a esa base y si por alguna razón se encuentra bloqueada la tabla la base de datos automaticamente toma el registro de tempdb, es como un estilo de replicación y si mejoró muchísimo, de hecho LAS BASES DE AZURE DB UTILIZAN ESA CONFIGURACIÓN POR DEFAULT y en las bases tradicionales hay que hacerlo manual
para que ya empiece utilizar esa configuración, les recomiendo ver el siguiente vídeo:

[Video que explica los tipos de ISOLATION de las bases de
datos incluido el de  COMMITED_SNAPSHOT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk59VS8d0bo&list=PLSMRJOqKwI-MiK7NYCaeLyeZp5iyhz10O&index=4)

Resultados:

[image: Resultados]